# Fork in client in a client server programme

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to learn socket programming. So my question is that if you fork a child on the client after connecting to a socket i.e. after doing the connect call. Then can you read and write independently using socket descriptor in the child and the parent? Server only knows one socket. So if you are reading fast at the child than at the parent. Will there be data loss at the parent?

Comment: Yes. If two processes try to act on the same connection, they will compete.

Comment: @PSkocik does creating a child not replicate the socket itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If two processes try to act on the same connection, they will compete.

Forking will duplicate the connection's file descriptor (as with `dup`/`dup2`/`dup3`), but those two filedescriptors will just be two counted references to the same connection.

Practically that means most fd-taking syscalls (`read()`,`write()`,...) will get through to the shared target file (the actual connection), however `close()` calls will only decrement the ref count and will only initiate a connection shutdown (as with the `shutdown()` syscall) when the refcount becomes `0`.